# protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter doesn't show results for all test when using with restartBrowserBetweenTests: true

Tags: protractor

protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter doesn't show results for all test when using with restartBrowserBetweenTests: true, it shows the report for last test "it" only. 
if there is a way to consolidate all the results? like we had in jasmine1 html reporter? I tried setting consolidateAll flag but I don't see any difference